# check if value already exists in the JSON added using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code that I use to add dropdown list for each row in specific row filled with JSON values. And it works great...but now what I want to do is to be able to check if there already exists value at the given cell. If it exists to check if this value exists in the JSON , if yes then this value should be set as **SELECTED** option (selected="selected"). but I can't get it to work.

this is the working code

```
 selectCI = ""
optionCI = "<option>SELECT CI</option>"
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"{{url_for('CI')}}",
    success: function(result){
        $("#my_id tr").each(function(){
            data = JSON.parse(result);
            if($(this).find("td:eq(15)")[0]){
                $(data).each(function(key,item){
                    optionCI += '<option value=' + item.CIValue + '>' + item.CI + '</option>';
            });
            selectCI = '<select id="CISelect" type="select-CI">' + optionCI + '</select>'
            $(this).find("td:eq(15)").append(selectCI);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

and this is what I tried so far:

```
selectCI = ""
optionCI = "<option>SELECT CI</option>"
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"{{url_for('CI')}}",
    success: function(result){
        $("#my_id tr").each(function(){
            data = JSON.parse(result);
            if($(this).find("td:eq(15)")[0]){
                $(data).each(function(key,item){
                    if((item.CI.toLowerCase() === $(this).find("td:eq(15)")[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase())){
                        optionCI += '<option selected="selected" value="' + item.CIValue + '">' + item.CI + '</option>';
                    }else{
                        optionCI += '<option value=' + item.CIValue + '>' + item.CI + '</option>';
                    }
            });
            selectCI = '<select id="CISelect" type="select-CI">' + optionCI + '</select>'
            $(this).find("td:eq(15)").append(selectCI);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

but this gives me back an error : 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined**

and the data= JSON.parse(result);
returns this as my JSON:

```
0: {CI: "Computer", CIValue: "CMP"}
1: {CI: "Vertrag", CIValue: "CTR"}
2: {CI: "General Peripheral", CIValue: "GDV"}
3: {CI: "Lizenz", CIValue: "LIC"}
4: {CI: "Mobile Device", CIValue: "MOB"}
```

Any help would be great

**EDIT** :
I think the problem is that this innerHTML does the checks before the page is fully rendered and that is what is causing the problem...but I am NO expert in this

**EDIT 2**
as sugested I used **$tr(this)** but it gave me double values when more than one row are in table which have a value from before.

[image: first is how it is in first row]  [image: second row]

there should be 11 values in each dropdown but for each next row I get 11 extra. So at the 5 row it has 11*5 values :/

**EDIT 3** 
this is the current version of the snippet code:

```
   selectCI = ""
optionCI = "<option selected='selected' id='sel'>Select CI</option>"
flag = false
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"{{url_for('CI')}}",
    success: function(result){
        $("#my_id tr").each(function(){
            const $tr = $(this);
            if($tr.find("td:eq(15)")[0]){
                data = JSON.parse(result);
                $(data).each(function(key,item){
                    if((item.CI.toLowerCase() === $tr.find("td:eq(15)")[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) || (item.CIValue.toLowerCase() === $tr.find("td:eq(15)")[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) ){
                        optionCI += '<option selected="selected" value="' + item.CIValue + '">' + item.CI + '</option>';
                        flag = true;
                    }else{
                        optionCI += '<option value=' + item.CIValue + '>' + item.CI + '</option>';
                    }
                });
                classObject = !flag ? 'errorDropDown' : '';
                selectCI = '<select id="CISelect" class="first' + ' ' + classObject + '"  type="select-CI">' + optionCI + '</select>';
                if(flag){
                    $(this).find("td:eq(15)").html(selectCI);
                }else{
                    $(this).find("td:eq(15)").append(selectCI);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML content?

Comment: The problem is this`$(this).find("td:eq(15)")`.  Are you sure that's a working find expression?  Try `console.log($(this).find("td:eq(15)"))` at the beginning of your function to check it.

Comment: well I already did this check but from arrays created in the JS and it worked. I mean I used almost identical code for check if the value exists in the array that is in the JS hard coded and it found values :/

Comment: I mean if I do the first code you can see in my question, I get the dropdown list in the "td:eq(15)"

Comment: You can replace `$(data).each(function(key, item) {` with `data.forEach(function(item, key) {` which will keep the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're mapping through your `data` the context `this` changes.

In the following scenario, your `this` represents your `tr`

```
$("#my_id tr").each(function(){
  // this === tr
  if($(this).find("td:eq(15)")[0]){
    // code
  }
});
```

However, later you do something like this:

```
$(data).each(function(key, item) {
  // this === current item
  if ((item.CI.toLowerCase() === $(this).find("td:eq(15)")[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase())) {
    optionCI += '<option selected="selected" value="' + item.CIValue + '">' + item.CI + '</option>';
  } else {
    optionCI += '<option value=' + item.CIValue + '>' + item.CI + '</option>';
  }
});
```

Your context `this` should now represent your current item. In fact, I'm sure if you do `item.CI.toLowerCase() === this.CI.toLowerCase()` it would be true.

To solve your problem, create a variable where you store your jquery `tr` element, so it'll be available in the next `each`.

```
const $tr = $(this);
$(data).each(function(key, item) {
  if ((item.CI.toLowerCase() === $tr.find("td:eq(15)")[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase())) {
    optionCI += '<option selected="selected" value="' + item.CIValue + '">' + item.CI + '</option>';
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much ..... it worked :D I was loosing my mind over this one

Comment: @AmilaBečirović no worries :) it happens to everyone eventually, good luck with the project.

Comment: hi just a follow up question , I just noticed that my code now adds previous dropdown values for each row (ever since I added the **const $tr** )... do you maybe have an idea how to fix that ?

Comment: I edited my question and added screenshots. thank you for the help

Comment: yes , each row should have same amount of available options. In this particular case with CI should each time have 11 options. As I look now , it seems as it copies each time..